# Given two subgroups what are the relationes of the commutators of the two subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $N\triangleleft G.$ Let $S_N$ be the set of commutators in $N$, i.e. $S_N \subset N, \,aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in S_N $with $ a,b \in G$ and $S_H$ the set of commutators in $H$, i.e.$\,S_H \subset H, \,cdc^{-1}d^{-1}\in S_H$ with $c, d \in G.$

What holds in general, $S_N=S_H, S_N\subset S_H$ or $S_H\subset S_N$ in the two cases

$1.\,\, H\cap N=\{e\}$, and $2.\,\,H\cap N\neq \{e\}$ ?

Comment: How come $\;a,b\in G\;$ for the set of commutators **of** $\;N\;$ , and like wise for $\;S_H\;$ ?? Or you mean the set of commutators *of the whole group* $\;G\;$ that are contained in $\;N\;$ (in $\;H\;$ , resp.) ?

Comment: Yes, by $S_N$ I meant the set of commutators of $G$ contained in $N$ and likewise for $S_H.$ That is how it is written in an algebra book.

Comment: I think you can lots of test cases in the group $\text{Symm}(3)\times\text{Symm}(3)$.

Comment: If $H\cap N =\{e\}$ then the only possible commutator in both is $e$, which is indeed a commutator ($e=eee^{-1}e^{-1}$) so $S_N\cap S_H=\{e\}$ in this case. This suggests that the second condition also will not tell you much about the relationship of the sets of commutators. If the intersection of $H$ and $N$ is small, why should there be any significant relationship here?

Comment: @Mark Bennet. What makes the difference if the intersection $H\cap N$ is small or not ?

Comment: If the intersection is small there are not many elements which can be in both $S_H$ and $S_N$, so postulating a significant relationship between them looks likely to fail.